# jsp update query not working

Tags: jsp, sql-update

This is my jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="com.dbcon.util.Dbconnect"%>
<%
    String password = request.getParameter("newpass");
    String retypePass = request.getParameter("retypenewpass");
    String uname = request.getParameter("f_name");
    Connection con = Dbconnect.getMySqlConnection();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    int i = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE Customers SET PASSWORD='" + password + "' and RETYPE_PASSWORD='" + retypePass + " WHERE USERNAME='" + uname +"'");              

    if (i > 0) {
        out.println("Password Changed <a href='login.jsp'>click here</a> to login");
    } else {
        out.println("Wrong passwords");
        response.sendRedirect("forgot.jsp");
    }
%>
```

the error is

```
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /newpasschecker.jsp at line 10

7:  String uname = request.getParameter("f_name");
8:     Connection con = Dbconnect.getMySqlConnection();
9:  Statement st = con.createStatement();
10:     int i = st.executeUpdate("UPDATE Customers SET PASSWORD='" + password + "' and RETYPE_PASSWORD='" + retypePass + " WHERE USERNAME='" + uname +"'");              
11:  
12:     if (i > 0) {
13:         out.println("Password Changed <a href='login.jsp'>click here</a> to login");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

any help would be appreciated ....

Comment: Something (error message, part of stack trace) is missing here - there should be more detailed description of **what** is the problem on that line. Check the log file and add more info.

Comment: Btw. your code contains two things you should really avoid to use: 1) **do not** create SQL statements by concatenating strings - use `PreparedStatement`; read [why](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc.html); 2) **avoid** putting business logic into JSP, use [MVC](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) approach, or at least put the code into a helper class and call this class from JSP;